# Unable to do the union in stored procedure for selected queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Usp_SelectQuestion]
   @NoOfQuestion int
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @CNT int
  Declare @test int
  Declare @x int
  Declare @y int

  set @x = 1;
  set @y = 1; 
  set @CNT=(Select Count(*) from (select Distinct(setno)from onlin) AS A)
  set @test=@NoOfQuestion/@CNT

  while (@x <= @CNT)  
  begin
    select top (@test) * from onlin where setno = @x order by NEWID()
      set @x = @x + 1
  end
END
```

In this stored procedure I am getting output as single table for every loop so I am getting multiple tables as output but I want all rows in a single table I think through union we can achieve but I do not know how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @temptable as table(col1 int, col2 varchar(50),... etc)

  while (@x <= @CNT)  
  begin
     insert into @temptable   'temptable columns need to match columns in the SELECT statement
        select top (@test) * from onlin where setno = @x order by NEWID()

     set @x = @x + 1
  end

  select * from @temptable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM tableName;
```

then insert to table

```
INSERT INTO tableName SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `temp table` and insert into that in the loop and then the result will be the:

```
SELECT * FROM tempTable
```